# Is this a typo from my professor regarding this question on distribution function?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions

Is this a typo from my professor?

In the above picture is the question and in the bottom one is the solution provided by the professor. In the solution, instead of P(X>=0.5) = 0.5, shouldn't it be P(X>=0.5) = 0.5P(X=0.5)?

And in the first sentence of the solution, why do we write X = XI_{x<0.5}) + XI_{x>=0.5} instead of, for example, X = XI_{x<=0.5} + XI_{x>0.5} considering that's how the distribution is written in the curve brackets in the question?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The distribution function $F$ should be *right continuous*, so the definition should be $F(x)=x$ for $0<x<{1\over 2}$ and $F(x)=1$ for ${1\over 2}\leq x$. Then you get a uniform distribution on $(0, {1\over 2})$ together with a point mass at $x={1\over 2}$, with equal probability for each case, which is clearly what is intended.

In the answer, the statement should be that $P(X<0.5)=0.5$ instead of $P(X=0.5)=0.5$ (which, incidentally, also happens to be true, and which may be the cause of confusion here).

Comment: Thank you. And in the answer, what should P(X>=0.5) be? And this is a silly question but I'm new to probability so what's the exact difference between P(X) and F(X)? I understand that P refers to probability and F a function but for instance, you wrote (=0.5)=0.5  but you also said that F(X) = 1 when that happens. I understand that F(X) = 1 because that's given in the question but how did you calculate (=0.5)=0.5? And will the final answer still be 3/8 as shown in the picture?

Comment: The statement in the answer about $P(X\geq 0.5)$ is correct, since this is the probability of observing the point mass at $x={1\over 2}$. The computation of the expected value ${\rm E}X={3\over 8}$ is also correct. If you are new to probability, you need to be careful with the difference between large and small letters. Here $F(x)$ is an ordinary function with an ordinary real variable $x$, but $P$ is a completely different animal, giving the probability of various events. The connection between $F$ and $P$ is given by $F(x)=P(X\leq x)$.

Comment: By the way, if P(X>=0.5) = 0.5, then how is E(XI_{x>=0.5})= 0.5P(X=0.5) as shown in the last line of the answer? What's the difference between P(X>=0.5) and E(XI_{x>=0.5})?

Comment: Again, you need to be careful with large and small letters. $X\cdot {\rm I}_{X\geq 0.5}$ is a stochastic variable that can only take two values, $0$ and $1\over 2$, each with probability $1\over 2$.

Comment: Thanks. Another question is for E(XI_{x<0.5}), why don't we multiply the integral of x with P(X=0.5) as we did in the case for E(XI_{x>=0.5})? The formula for E(X) asks us to also multiply with the probability, yes? Why don't we do that in the case of E(XI_{x<0.5})? Why just the integral of x?

Comment: Please note that comments are not for asking new questions. If you have problems with computing expected values, you can pose another question about it.

Comment: Thanks. Just asked: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4598581/how-do-we-calculate-ex-here