# How do we calculate E(X) here?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions

In the solution in the picture below, for $E(XI_{x<0.5})$, why don't we multiply the integral of $x$ with $P(X=0.5)$ as we did in the case for $E(XI_{x\geq0.5})$? The formula for $E(X)$ asks us to also multiply with the probability, yes? Why don't we do that in the case of $E(XI_{X<0.5})$? Why just the integral of $x$?
[image]

Comment: I don't understand the distribution.  How can $F(x)=0$ if $0≤x$ but $F(x)=x$ if $0<x<\frac 12$?  What exactly is $F(.25)$?  I'm guessing the first line was meant to be $F(x)=0$ if $x≤\frac 12$ but that's just a guess.

Comment: In any case, once the definition is corrected, this is just a piecewise linear function.  Should be easy to do the relevant integral (just a sum of terms, in this case).

Comment: @lulu its obviously a typo, it must be $F(x)=0$ when $x\leqslant 0$, instead of $x\geqslant 0$. But you know that, why are you trolling?

Comment: To your question:  you *are* multiplying by the probability density here.  $F(x)$ is not the probability density, rather it is the cumulative probability. The density, in the range $0≤x≤.5$ is just $1$ and, of course, $x\times 1$ is just $x$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to think of $X$ as a mixed random variable, i.e. it's both continuous and discrete. As such, the expectation takes the following form:

$$E[X] = \int x f_X(x) dx + \sum x_i P(X= x_i)$$

Hence,
$$E[X] = 
\int_0^{0.5} x f_X(x) dx +0.5 P(X=0.5) = \int_0^{0.5} x dx + \frac{1}{4}= \frac{x^2}{2}\Big|_0^{0.5} + \frac{1}{4} = \frac{1}{8} + \frac{1}{4} = \frac{3}{8} $$

Where we use the fact that the continuous density function is the derivative of the cumulative function. Since in $(0,1/2)$ $F(x) = x$ we have that $f_X(x) = 1$.

Comment: How do I know that I have to think of X as a mixed random variable (continuous and discrete)?

Comment: Look at how the exercise defines the random variable. It essentially says that $X = Unif(0,1/2)$ with probability $1/2$ (continuous part) or $X = 1/2$ with probability $1/2$, i.e. $P(X=1/2) = 1/2$ (discrete part).

Answer (score 0):

One way of looking at this is to say there is probability $\frac12$ that $X$ is uniformly distributed between $0$ and $\frac12$ (a conditional mean of $\frac14$ as the midpoint of a uniform distribution) and probability $\frac12$ that $X$ is exactly $\frac12$ (a conditional mean of $\frac12$ as a single point).

The overall mean is then $\frac12 \times \frac14 + \frac 12 \times \frac12=\frac18+\frac14 =\frac38$ as in the provided solution.

If you look at the unconditional density between $0$ and $\frac12$  then this is $\frac{dF(x)}{dx} = 1$ and its contribution to the overall mean (multiplying by $x$ and integrating) is $\int_0^{1/2}\, x\times 1\, dx =\frac18$.

Alternatively you could have said the conditional density was $2$ on that interval and found its contribution to the mean was $ \frac12 \int_0^{1/2}\, x\times 2\, dx =\frac18$ again.